# How to insert CurrentUserId and TenantId fields in target table while copying data from csv to sql table

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have gone through https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-copy-activity-tutorial-using-dotnet-api and have it running. 
Along with CSV file columns i want to insert CurrentUserId and TenantId like fields in the target table while copying data from csv to azure sql table. How to achieve that? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: .csv support is built-in to the Azure Data Factory Copy activity, can I just ask, why the custom task?

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not supported. Please go in and vote for this feature to be added: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/17332714-allow-adding-of-additional-columns-to-data-source